# <DOCTYPE html> versus <html> - rendering problems firefox and chrome

Tags: html, doctype

have been using no `DOCTYPE` but rather simply starting with `<html>` as per HTML5 standards (as I understood them).  everything going ok.

began using `Jade`, which insists on `DOCTYPE`. using `<!DOCTYPE html>` - pages no longer render correctly(?).

as an easy and trivial example (behavior is same on firefox and chrome):

```
<html>
    <body >
        <div style='height:50%; background-color:pink;'></div>
        <div style='height:50%; background-color:blue;'></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

render just fine - have page pink, half blue

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body >
        <div style='height:50%; background-color:pink;'></div>
        <div style='height:50%; background-color:blue;'></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

renders two skinny DIV's you can't see.

1. what's going on?
2. thought `DOCTYPE` was being deprecated for HTML5
3. what should I be doing?

Comment: Actually, not only is the `DOCTYPE` required, I *think* it's the only element that *is* required: `<!DOCTYPE html>` is a valid HTML5 document all by itself.

Comment: @ultranaut, no, the required `DOCTYPE` preamble is not an element at all, and if you use a validator, you will see that the `title` element is required in markup. (The `html`, `head`, and `body` element are always present, but their start and end tags are optional.)

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela fair enough sir, the `DOCTYPE` is not an element. It's my understanding that under certain circumstances the `title` element isn't required though, e.g. in the context of an email?

Comment: @ultranaut: Yes, in some contexts (http://stackoverflow.com/a/11943126/1591669)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Whoever who told you that `DOCTYPE` is deprecated is either playing a prank on you or is plain ignorant.

---

W3C on its article [**HTML5 differences from HTML4**](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5-diff/) on the section `Syntax`, sub section 2.2 clearly states this.

> **The HTML syntax of HTML5 requires a doctype to be specified** to ensure
>   that the browser renders the page in standards mode. The doctype has
>   no other purpose and is therefore optional for XML. Documents with an
>   XML media type are always handled in standards mode. [[DOCTYPE](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5-diff/#refsDOCTYPE)]
>
> The doctype declaration is `<!DOCTYPE html>` and is case-insensitive in
>   the HTML syntax. Doctypes from earlier versions of HTML were longer
>   because the HTML language was SGML-based and therefore required a
>   reference to a DTD. With HTML5 this is no longer the case and the
>   doctype is only needed to enable standards mode for documents written
>   using the HTML syntax. Browsers already do this for `<!DOCTYPE html>`.

And as to, why the behavior when you set `<!DOCTYPE html>` in your example.

This behavior is expected. This is because `body` is a block level element. So it has height, by default, in a `shrink-to-fit` model and width, by default, in an `expand-to-fit` model. Setting `style="height:100%;"` in the `body` tag allows body to take up the whole of the height available and displays your two divs.

Comment: Body does not have height. It inherits height from `<html>`, which inherits it from the viewport.

Answer (score 16):

1. Without a `DOCTYPE`, the page is rendered in Quirks Mode. This means dozens of oddities. The one you have encountered is #3 in my list of [Quirks Mode phenomena](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/quirks-mode.html): percentage  heights for elements are applied, using the available height as reference, even when the enclosing block has `height: auto` (the default); by the specs, the height is determined by the require­ments of the content.
2. No, `DOCTYPE` is not deprecated according to HTML5 drafts – on the contrary, it is required, but any form other than `<!DOCTYPE html>` is declared obsolete.
3. For new pages, design them to work in “Standards Mode” (and of course use `<!DOCTYPE html>`). For old pages, it depends.

In the given case, to make the browser’s rendering area divided in the intended way, set the height of the `html` and `body` elements, thereby making percentage heights apply to elements inside the body even in “Standards Mode”:

```
<style>
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why those DIVs were showing up before your change.

But your DOCTYPE declaration is correct for HTML5 - see http://www.w3.org/TR/html5-diff/#doctype .

And, if you add height: 100% to HTML and BODY you'll see those elements. They're taking up 50% of their container's height, which is 0, so their height is also 0. See http://jsfiddle.net/sync/EUXTY/ .

Comment: right you are - thanks!  interesting that 100% needs to be added to both `html` and `body`