# HTML not stretching to window on sever but working locally

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

I am facing a strange issue while creating a responsive webpage.

Basically, I created a simple html page(Page 1) and uploaded it to a blob storage. The page is then run in Azure AD's B2C portal which inserts login form into my html page (using CORS)  and shows the combined page to the user. Since I have the source code of the final combined page(Page 2) which automatically merges my content with Azure's form, I am able to test the page from my local machine as well.

The issues I am facing is that Page 1 (which I upload to blob) stretches to window perfectly (both height and width), but Page-2 after it's merged with Azure login-form does not stretch along height.

I have already verified using chrome developer tools (enabled using F12 on chrome) that css style on html/body in page2 is the one I applied and only other thing added to it by browser/Azure is {display: block;} which I think should not cause this current issue.

Below are the source codes :-

Page 1 :

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>User Details</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <!-- 
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=2.0, user-scalable=yes">
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
            <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://login.microsoftonline.com/static/tenant/default/css/common-1.0.4.css">
            <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://login.microsoftonline.com/static/tenant/default/css/selfAsserted.1.0.8.css"> 
            <script src="https://login.microsoftonline.com/static/tenant/default/js/layout-1.0.0.min.js"></script>-->
        <style>
        #main_div {
        background-image:url('https://adasphase2.blob.core.windows.net/democontainerblockblob/mm_background.jpg'); 
        /* background-color: 00ff00; */
        height:100%;
        width:100%;
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        background-size:100% 100%; 
        }
        body {
        /*background-color: #ff00ff;*/
        height:100%;
        width:100%;
        }
        h1 {
        font-size: 3vw;
        letter-spacing: 0px;
        color:#F8F8F8;
        font-family: sans-serif;
        padding:0% 5% 5% 5%;
        }
        img {
        width:100%; 
        padding-top:10%;  
        /*padding-top:10%; 
        padding-left:5%; 
        padding-right:5%*/
        }
        label[for=password] {
        display: none;
        }
        h2 {
        display: none;
        }
        {
        }
        label[for=logonIdentifier] {
        display: none;
        }
        #forgotPassword {
        display: none;
        }
        #password, #logonIdentifier {
        margin: 2% 5% 2% 5%;
        width: 90%;
        }
        #password, #logonIdentifier {
        margin: 1% 5%;
        width: 86%;
        padding: 2% 2%;
        }
        #next {
        background-color: #222222;
        border-style: solid;
        border-radius: 5px;
        border-color: #ffffff;
        color: white;
        padding: 2% 2%;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 3vw;
        font-family: sans-serif;
        border-width: 1px;
        width: 90%;
        margin: 2% 5%;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-weight: bold;
        }
        #next:active {
        background-color: #444444;
        }
        div.create {
        display: none;
        }
        #forgot{
        font-size: 3vw;
        letter-spacing: 0px;
        color:#F8F8F8;
        font-family: sans-serif;
        margin:2% 5%
        }
        </style
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="main_div">
            <img id="background_background_image" src="https://adasphase2.blob.core.windows.net:443/democontainerblockblob/splash_stacked_logo.png" alt="Illustration" />
            <h1>LOGIN WITH A TARPPORTAL.COM ACCOUNT OR CLICK REGISTER FOR A NEW ACCOUNT.</h1>
            <div id="api"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Page2 (combined page):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- Build: 1.0.0.114 -->
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Loading...</title>
        <script src="https://login.microsoftonline.com/static/library/require-2.1.17.min.js"></script>
        <script>window.staticHost="https://login.microsoftonline.com/static";window.targetSlice="001-000";</script>
        <script>var elementUrl="elements/selfasserted/unifiedSSP-1.0.8.min";</script>
        <script>define('template.CP', [/** no dependencies. **/], {"list":[]});
            define('template.SA_FIELDS', [/** no dependencies. **/], {"AttributeFields":[{"IS_TEXT":true,"IS_PASSWORD":false,"IS_DATE":false,"IS_RADIO":false,"IS_DROP":false,"IS_CHECK_MULTI":false,"IS_LINK":false,"VERIFY":false,"DN":"LogonIdentifier","ID":"logonIdentifier","U_HELP":"","DAY_PRE":"0","MONTH_PRE":"0","YEAR_PRE":"0","IS_REQ":true,"IS_RDO":false},{"IS_TEXT":false,"IS_PASSWORD":true,"IS_DATE":false,"IS_RADIO":false,"IS_DROP":false,"IS_CHECK_MULTI":false,"IS_LINK":false,"VERIFY":false,"DN":"Password","ID":"password","U_HELP":"Enter password","DAY_PRE":"0","MONTH_PRE":"0","YEAR_PRE":"0","IS_REQ":true,"IS_RDO":false}]});
            
            
            define('language.data', [/** no dependencies. **/], {"email_pattern":"^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&amp;’*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$","logonIdentifier_email":"Email Address","requiredField_email":"Please enter your email","logonIdentifier_username":"Username","createaccount_link":"Sign up now","requiredField_username":"Please enter your user name","createaccount_intro":"Don&#39;t have an account?","forgotpassword_link":"Forgot your password?","divider_title":"OR","cancel_message":"The user has forgotten their password","button_signin":"Sign in","social_intro":"Sign in with your social account","requiredField_password":"Please enter your password","invalid_password":"The password you entered is not in the expected format.","local_intro_username":"Sign in with your user name","local_intro_email":"Sign in with your existing account","invalid_email":"Please enter a valid email address","unknown_error":"We are having trouble signing you in. Please try again later."});
            
            define('settings.data', [/** no dependencies. **/], {"remoteResource":"https://adasphase2.blob.core.windows.net/democontainerblockblob/RemoteServicesLoginPage.html","retryLimit":3,"api":"CombinedSigninAndSignup","csrf":"R2lYeVl1cEJLYWlpdENnSHJoOHpITHZtWWFaR2Y4eCsvcUZiK3JsTDd5OXFBZFAzUDViNDBtSTczUTd1YnpPS3RpVURmd1dPOGM1K0FZYU5Fam1IRkE9PTsyMDE2LTA1LTE4VDIyOjEzOjU3LjQxNTEwMjJaO0F6U0VkYlRUbDlHenNoQkVHK1JYSUE9PTt7Ik9yY2hlc3RyYXRpb25TdGVwIjoxfQ==","transId":"eyJUSUQiOiJmN2I4ODJjOS03NmJlLTQ0MzktYWJjNi1hNzE1NjM3ZDM4MGQifQ","pageMode":0,"config":{"operatingMode":"Email","sendHintOnSignup":"False","forgotPasswordLinkLocation":"AfterLabel","includePasswordRequirements":"true"},"hosts":{"tenant":"/lexustmstest.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_TMS_Lexus_SignUpandSignIn_Policy","policy":"B2C_1_TMS_Lexus_SignUpandSignIn_Policy","static":"https://login.microsoftonline.com/static/"},"locale":{"lang":"en","country":"US"}});
            
        </script>
        <script>var cookieEnabled=navigator.cookieEnabled?!0:!1,Constants;typeof navigator.cookieEnabled!="undefined"||cookieEnabled||(document.cookie="probe",cookieEnabled=document.cookie.indexOf("probe")!=-1?!0:!1),function(){document.querySelectorAll||(document.querySelectorAll=function(n){var i=i=document.createStyleSheet(),r=document.all,f=r.length,t,u=[];for(i.addRule(n,"k:v"),t=0;t<f;t+=1)if(r[t].currentStyle.k==="v"&&(u.push(r[t]),u.length>Infinity))break;return i.removeRule(0),u});String.prototype.trim||function(){var n=/^[\s\uFEFF\xA0]+|[\s\uFEFF\xA0]+$/g;String.prototype.trim=function(){return this.replace(n,"")}}()}();cookieEnabled&&(Constants=[],Constants.ERROR_REDIRECT_CONSOLE_STRING="Redirecting back to B2C service with querystring",function(){for(var n,u=function(){},t=["assert","clear","count","debug","dir","dirxml","error","exception","group","groupCollapsed","groupEnd","info","log","markTimeline","profile","profileEnd","table","time","timeEnd","timeStamp","trace","warn"],i=t.length,r=window.console=window.console||{};i--;)n=t[i],r[n]||(r[n]=u)}(),require(["require"],function(){require.config({baseUrl:window.staticHost,paths:{jquery:"library/jquery-1.10.2.min",handlebars:"library/handlebars-2.0.0.min",requirecss:"library/require-css-0.1.8.min",simpleModal:"library/jquery.simplemodal-1.4.5.min",core:"js/core-1.0.17.min",metrics:"js/metrics-1.0.1.min",modal:"js/modal-1.0.1.min",iso:"js/iso-unified-1.0.2.min",element:elementUrl},map:{"*":{css:"requirecss"}},skipDataMain:!0});require(["core","settings.data","metrics","element"],function(n,t,i,r){try{window.Metrics=i;metricResource=window.Metrics.create(t.remoteResource);metricResource.start();function u(){var i,f=canSetHeaders=!0,e=t.retryLimit;window.XDomainRequest?(i=new XDomainRequest,f=canSetHeaders=!1):i=new XMLHttpRequest;i.open("GET",metricResource.id);canSetHeaders&&metricResource.id.indexOf(window.staticHost)===0&&i.setRequestHeader("x-ms-cpim-slice",window.targetSlice);i.onload=function(){var t,u;if(!f||f&&i.status===200){metricResource.end();t=(new Date).getTime();r.initialize(i.responseText);metricResource.setInitializationTime((new Date).getTime()-t);return}u="external?statusCode="+i.status+"&resource="+encodeURIComponent(metricResource.id);n.redirectToServer(u);return};i.onerror=function(){var t=0,r;f&&(t=i.status);r="external?statusCode="+t+"&resource="+encodeURIComponent(metricResource.id);n.redirectToServer(r)};i.timeout=function(){if(this.tryCount++,this.tryCount<=this.retryLimit){u();return}var t="external?statusCode=4&resource="+encodeURIComponent(metricResource.id);n.redirectToServer(t);return};i.onprogress=function(){};i.send()}u()}catch(f){n.redirectToServer("error?statusCode=0&statusMessage="+encodeURIComponent(f.message)+"&resource="+encodeURIComponent(t.remoteResource))}})}))</script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <style>.no_display{display:none}.error_container h1{color:#333;font-size:1.2em;font-family:'Segoe UI Light',Segoe,'Segoe UI',SegoeUI-Light-final,Tahoma,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-weight:lighter}.error_container p{color:#333;font-size:.8em;font-family:'Segoe UI',Segoe,SegoeUI-Regular-final,Tahoma,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;margin:14px 0}</style>
        <noscript>
            <div id="no_js">
                <div class="error_container">
                    <div>
                        <h1>We can't sign you in</h1>
                        <p>Your browser is currently set to block JavaScript. You need to allow JavaScript to use this service.</p>
                        <p>To learn how to allow JavaScript or to find out whether your browser supports JavaScript, check the online help in your web browser.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </noscript>
        <div id="no_cookie" class="no_display">
            <div class="error_container">
                <div>
                    <h1>We can't sign you in</h1>
                    <p>Your browser is currently set to block cookies. You need to allow cookies to use this service.</p>
                    <p>Cookies are small text files stored on your computer that tell us when you're signed in. To learn how to allow cookies, check the online help in your web browser.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script>if (!cookieEnabled) document.getElementById('no_cookie').className = '';</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Any help/pointers are appreciated !

Comment: Obervation -  <!DOCTYPE html> is messing with CSS. Removing it resolves the issue. But the problem is that it is inserted by the server and further, I beleive this declaration is required. So, is there a way out?

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
body, html { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

On line 1 of your first page add

```
<!doctype html>
```

and then further down you have a typo on the closing style tag

```
</style      <-------- 
    </head>
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your help. I found this post helpful :
[Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12870294/doctype-html-versus-html-rendering-problems-firefox-and-chrome)

Adding html{ height:100%; } resolved the issue.