# Bare minimum HTML5 - is it valid?

Tags: html

I was reading up on D3, and one of the slides mentioned the [most minimal HTML page](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/d3/workshop/#8) by Paul Irish.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<body>
Hello, world!
```

I understand exactly what this HTML does -- however, how in the world could this be valid HTML5, and further, is it standards compliant? Or is this just a case of *it works, but it bends the rules*?

Comment: [w3 validator](http://validator.w3.org/check) says this: Error Line 3, Column 6: Element head is missing a required instance of child element title.

Comment: @Paolo using which standards compliant validator, in which mode?

Comment: Default settings, I guess HTML5 validation.

Comment: For whomever flagged as "Primarily opinion based", please re-read my question again and review the close reason.

Comment: Related (uses exactly the same example): [Is this minimalist HTML5 markup valid?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11942116/1591669)

Comment: Related: [Is it necessary to write HEAD, BODY and HTML tags?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5641997/1591669)

Comment: @unor Yep, you're right, but the answer here is much better in my opinion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5) describes what tags can be omitted under **Tag omission in text/html**. However, the [spec states](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#element-dfn-tag-omission):

> A *non-normative* description of whether, in the text/html syntax, the
>   start and end tags can be omitted. This information is redundant with
>   the normative requirements given in the optional tags section, and is
>   provided in the element definitions only as a convenience.

Since it's non-normative, we can not rely on it for conformance checking. In the normative [optional tags](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#syntax-tag-omission) section, it lists:

> An html element's start tag may be omitted if the first thing inside
>   the html element is not a comment.
>
> An html element's end tag may be omitted if the html element is not
>   immediately followed by a comment.
>
> A head element's start tag may be omitted if the element is empty, or
>   if the first thing inside the head element is an element.
>
> A head element's end tag may be omitted if the head element is not
>   immediately followed by a space character or a comment.
>
> A body element's start tag may be omitted if the element is empty, or
>   if the first thing inside the body element is not a space character or
>   a comment, except if the first thing inside the body element is a
>   meta, link, script, style, or template element.
>
> A body element's end tag may be omitted if the body element is not
>   immediately followed by a comment.

So it seems the document is valid save for the missing [`<title>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/title), which is probably why the [w3 validator](http://validator.w3.org/) complains. There are further indications that `<title>` is required. First, the **Content model** section for [`<head>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#the-head-element), which is normative, states:

> If the document is an iframe srcdoc document or if title information
>   is available from a higher-level protocol: Zero or more elements of
>   metadata content, of which no more than one is a title element and no
>   more than one is a base element.
>
> Otherwise: One or more elements of metadata content, of which exactly
>   one is a title element and no more than one is a base element.

And the [spec states](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#element-dfn-content-model):

> A normative description of what content must be included as children
>   and descendants of the element.