# Center my text, but keep left align?

Tags: html, css

Im trying to make my links on my page left-aligned but centered on the page. How do I do this? I have tryed many ways and googled many more I haven't been codeing very long and this is becoming a real strugle.

[My site](https://conspiracy-theories.000webhostapp.com/)

This is my Html code

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
 <Title> Conspiracy Theories </Title>
  </head>
   <link href="mystyle.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <Body>
     <img src="http://media.moddb.com/images/groups/1/9/8589/tin_foil_hat.gif" />
      <a <link href="WP1.html" type="text/html" style="text-decoration:none" rel="html"> EmDrive is being tested on the X-37B</a></li>
      <a <link href="WP2.html" type="text/html" style="text-decoration:none" rel="html"> Diesel Submarines</a></li>
      <a <link href="WP3.html" type="text/html" style="text-decoration:none" rel="html">Lethal B-21 vs. B-2 Stealth Bomber</a></li>
      <a <link href="WP4.html" type="text/html" style="text-decoration:none" rel="html"> Air Force Wants a New Fighter</a></li>
      <a <link href="WP5.html" type="text/html" style="text-decoration:none" rel="html"> King Tiger Tank : Super Weapon or Super Myth?</a></li>
      <a <link href="WP6.html" type="text/html" style="text-decoration:none" rel="html"> Ground Combat Vehicle (GCV)</a></li>
      <a <link href="WP7.html" type="text/html" style="text-decoration:none" rel="html"> 3 service men killed</a></li>
      <a <link href="WP8.html" type="text/html" style="text-decoration:none" rel="html"> US intercepts 2 Russian bombers</a></li>
      <a <link href="WP9.html" type="text/html" style="text-decoration:none" rel="html"> World reacts to US strikes</a></li>
    </div>
   </div>
  </Body>
 <h1>     </h1>
```

The css

```
img {
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  width: 10%;
}

a {
  line-height: 1.7em;
  display:block;
  margin-left: auto;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
}

body {
   background-image: 
   url("https://presentations.inxpo.com/SharedContent/VX/images/background-
   shell.jpg");
}
```

Comment: Can you explain a little more what you are trying to get it to look like?

Comment: your css link must be inside the <head> </head> also your links are wrong, code like this <a href="url">link text</a>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this? I also cleaned up your html a bit. You can play around with the width on the `ul.container`, this will move the 'list' to the left or right.

```css
img {
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  width: 10%;
}

a {
  line-height: 1.7em;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul.container {
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 60%;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}

main {
  background-image: url("https://presentations.inxpo.com/SharedContent/VX/images/background-
 shell.jpg");

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <Title> Conspiracy Theories </Title>
  <link href="mystyle.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>


<main>
  <img src="http://media.moddb.com/images/groups/1/9/8589/tin_foil_hat.gif" />

  <ul class="container">
    <li><a href="WP1.html" type="text/html"> EmDrive is being tested on the X-37B</a></li>
    <li><a href="WP2.html" type="text/html"> Diesel Submarines</a></li>
    <li><a href="WP3.html" type="text/html"> Lethal B-21 vs. B-2 Stealth Bomber</a></li>
    <li><a href="WP4.html" type="text/html"> Air Force Wants a New Fighter</a></li>
    <li><a href="WP5.html" type="text/html"> King Tiger Tank : Super Weapon or Super Myth?</a></li>
    <li><a href="WP6.html" type="text/html"> Ground Combat Vehicle (GCV)</a></li>
    <li><a href="WP7.html" type="text/html"> 3 service men killed</a></li>
    <li><a href="WP8.html" type="text/html"> US intercepts 2 Russian bombers</a></li>
    <li><a href="WP9.html" type="text/html"> World reacts to US strikes</a></li>

  </ul>

</main>
<h1> </h1>
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/scarsam/pbfvrtfd/) I added a container that is the width of the nav items with the `display: inline-block;` property. This div is wrapped and centered with the `text-align: center;` property. I changed the `a` text alignment from center > left to make the left aligned inside the div. I would also [validate](https://validator.w3.org/) the HTML because it looks like there is some error inside your code.

Check out this question for more information about a good HTML boilerplate. [A good HTML skeleton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4134019/a-good-html-skeleton)

Also check out this page if you want to clean up your code a bit [DirtyMarkup](https://dirtymarkup.com/)

### HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>
      Conspiracy Theories
    </title>
    <link href="mystyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <img src="http://media.moddb.com/images/groups/1/9/8589/tin_foil_hat.gif">
    <div class="text-center">
      <div class="display-inline">
        <a><link href="WP1.html" rel="html" style="text-decoration:none" type="text/html">EmDrive is being tested on the X-37B</a> 
        <a><link href="WP2.html" rel="html" style="text-decoration:none" type="text/html">Diesel Submarines</a>
        <a><link href="WP3.html" rel="html" style="text-decoration:none" type="text/html">Lethal B-21 vs. B-2 Stealth Bomber</a> 
        <a><link href="WP4.html" rel="html" style="text-decoration:none" type="text/html">Air Force Wants a New Fighter</a> 
        <a><link href="WP5.html" rel="html" style="text-decoration:none" type="text/html">King Tiger Tank : Super Weapon or Super Myth</a>       <a><link href="WP6.html" rel="html" style="text-decoration:none" type="text/html">Ground Combat Vehicle (GCV)</a> 
        <a><link href="WP7.html" rel="html" style="text-decoration:none" type="text/html">3 service men killed</a> 
        <a><link href="WP8.html" rel="html" style="text-decoration:none" type="text/html">US intercepts 2 Russian bombers</a> 
        <a><link href="WP9.html" rel="html" style="text-decoration:none" type="text/html">World reacts to US &gt;</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

### CSS

```
.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}

.display-inline {
  display: inline-block;
}

a {
  text-align: left;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a sample solution. I wrapped the links in a div to make this work. I hope it helps

```css
body {
    background-image: url(https://presentations.inxpo.com/SharedContent/VX/images/background-shell.jpg);
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: column;
}
img {
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    width: 10%;
}
body > div {
 text-align: left;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
a {
    line-height: 1.7em;
    display: block;
    color: black;
}
```

```html
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
 <Title> Conspiracy Theories </Title>
  </head>
   <link href="mystyle.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <Body>
     <img src="http://media.moddb.com/images/groups/1/9/8589/tin_foil_hat.gif" />
  <div>
      <a link href="WP1.html" type="text/html" style="text-decoration:none" rel="html"> EmDrive is being tested on the X-37B</a>
      <a link href="WP2.html" type="text/html" style="text-decoration:none" rel="html"> Diesel Submarines</a>
      <a link href="WP3.html" type="text/html" style="text-decoration:none" rel="html">Lethal B-21 vs. B-2 Stealth Bomber</a>
      <a link href="WP4.html" type="text/html" style="text-decoration:none" rel="html"> Air Force Wants a New Fighter</a>
      <a link href="WP5.html" type="text/html" style="text-decoration:none" rel="html"> King Tiger Tank : Super Weapon or Super Myth?</a>
      <a link href="WP6.html" type="text/html" style="text-decoration:none" rel="html"> Ground Combat Vehicle (GCV)</a>
      <a link href="WP7.html" type="text/html" style="text-decoration:none" rel="html"> 3 service men killed</a>
      <a link href="WP8.html" type="text/html" style="text-decoration:none" rel="html"> US intercepts 2 Russian bombers</a>
      <a link href="WP9.html" type="text/html" style="text-decoration:none" rel="html"> World reacts to US strikes</a>
    </div>
  </Body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
#app {
  /* step 2: center the text container in a flex box */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

/* step 3: be stylish */
#app, body, html {
  background: skyblue;
  color: royalblue;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <!-- step 1: wrap the text in a display:block element -->
  <div>
    <h2>foo bar</h2>
    <h2>lorem ipsum</h2>
    <span>hey hey</span><br />
    <span>blah blah blah</span>
  </div>  
</div>
```

[image]